# execute mysql query upon page exit/navigate away from page?

Tags: php, mysql

can anyone please tell me whether it is possible to run a mysl query that will run if a user navigates away from or exits the page?

for instance i have a table called sessions which i am using 'session_start' and 'session_end' to try and keep track of the users on my site. so in order to achieve a 'session_end' timestamp i wanted to know if it would be possible to update this column upon the user leaving the site?

there are also other ways of achieving this that im not thinking of, i would really appreciate anyones suggestions,

thanks in advance

Comment: This and many variations of it have been asked uncounted times before. The main point is that there is **no guarantee** that the browser will notify the server when the user leaves the page. Your session handling must not depend on this, and typical session handling doesn't. Sessions are all about timeouts and garbage collection, not explicit sign offs.

Comment: Ah... I guess from what deceze said made me do a double take on what the OP was asking. Answer is updated. Best regards.

Answer (score 3):

If this site has a login script / log out script you could

1. When a user ends a session (logs out) then you can run a query to update with the users session user-name and the time stamp
2. If a users session times out (possibly he leaves the website but does not log out) you could have a query run with the username and time stamp to have data on when a users session timed out and how long the session was alive for.
3. If a user logs in use that session user-name / inputted user-name to store the session data in the database.

These are just some ways of doing it (the first two ways that came to mind). Take a look at [sessions on PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) for further help. Also for the query stuff take a look at [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) Again I just want to reiterate this is the first two things that came to mind, and with the information provided I came up with the following recommendations. Hopefully this is some sort of help / a "AH - HAH!" moment. Enjoy sir.

> > Edit 1

If by any chance you are trying to have a query run once the browser is closed / a user hits a link to an external domain then no as deceze commented you can should not trust in the browser to notify the server. But like I posted above the edit you could use the above mentioned methods to do close to what you were asking.

Also don't forget to read up on [OWAPS's PHP session security cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet).. This and PHP user manual should be your best friends :D

Again hopefully this is some use to you!

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1: user login & logout - storing page ID (visited page) and time to track user - logout(session end)
2: Ajax script on every page - updates page id and timestamp every few seconds or minutes, if no update means user unavailable/left
3: php code on everypage, stores IP address, page ID and time stamp on each visit (if no new entry, user unavailable)